# What is the meaning of a non-canonical fixed point in the RG flow?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, renormalization, scaling

Consider, as an example, the Gaussian model:
$$
S[\phi]=\int\mathrm{d}\vec x\left[\frac{\gamma}{2}\left(\nabla\phi\right)^2+\frac{\mu^2}{2}\phi^2\right].
$$
RG analysis can be performed exactly by setting $x'=x/\ell$ and $\phi'=\zeta\phi$, so that
$$
S'[\phi']=\int\mathrm{d}\vec x'\left[\frac{\ell^{d-2}\zeta^2\gamma}{2}\left(\nabla'\phi'\right)^2+\frac{\ell^d\zeta^2{\mu^2}}{2}{\phi'}^2\right].
$$
The renormalized parameters are
$$
\gamma'(\ell)=\ell^{d-2}\zeta^2\gamma,\quad{\mu^2}'(\ell)=\ell^{d}\zeta^2\mu^2.
$$
Usually one performs canonical rescaling so that $\gamma'(\ell)=\gamma$, which means $\zeta=\ell^{1-d/2}$. Here $\mu^2$ (mass or temperature) controls the phase transition as it is the only relevant parameter.

What about using other forms for $\zeta$? I've seen some "massless" (but more complicated) theory where $\gamma$ was a relevant parameter. Is there a physical meaning for these theories?